# optimize R Script by looping

Tags: for-loop

how to loop the following script, basically, it is repetitive, but I am newbe and tried many time and failed. Your help will truly appreciated. thx a lot

fit1<-lm(Y1~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=test)
step1<-stepAIC(fit1)
step1$anova
print(step1)
summary(step1)$r.squared

fit2<-lm(Y2~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=test)
step2<-stepAIC(fit2)
step2$anova
print(step2)

fit3<-lm(Y3~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=test)
step3<-stepAIC(fit3)
step3$anova
print(step3)

fit4<-lm(Y4~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=test)
step4<-stepAIC(fit4)
step4$anova
print(step4)

fit5<-lm(Y5~x1+x2+x3+x4, data=test)
step5<-stepAIC(fit5)
step5$anova
print(step5)

fit6<-lm(Y6~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=test)
step6<-stepAIC(fit6)
step6$anova
print(step6)

fit7<-lm(Y7~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=test)
step7<-stepAIC(fit7)
step7$anova
print(step7)

fit8<-lm(Y8~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=test)
step8<-stepAIC(fit8)
step8$anova
print(step8)

fit9<-lm(Y9~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=test)
step9<-stepAIC(fit9)
step9$anova
print(step9)

fit10<-lm(Y10~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=test)
step10<-stepAIC(fit10)
step10$anova
print(step10)

fit11<-lm(Y11~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=test)
step11<-stepAIC(fit11)
step11$anova
print(step11)

fit12<-lm(Y12~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=test)
step12<-stepAIC(fit12)
step12$anova
print(step12)

fit13<-lm(Y13~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=test)
step13<-stepAIC(fit13)
step13$anova
print(step13)

fit14<-lm(Y14~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=test)
step14<-stepAIC(fit14)
step14$anova
print(step14)

fit15<-lm(Y15~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=test)
step15<-stepAIC(fit15)
step15$anova
print(step15)

fit16<-lm(Y16~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=test)
step16<-stepAIC(fit16)
step16$anova
print(step16)
fit17<-lm(Y17~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=test)
step17<-stepAIC(fit17)
step17$anova
print(step17)

fit18<-lm(Y18~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=test)
step18<-stepAIC(fit18)
step18$anova
print(step18)

Comment: please help !!!!

Comment: should loop these for Y1-Y18                 fit1-fit18, step1-step18                                                                                                                                                                                                          fit1<-lm(Y1~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=test)
step1<-stepAIC(fit1)
step1$anova
summary(step1)